# How can I update the boolean values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

My table has an `isSuccessful` column, I set the datatype as boolean (0 indicates false, 1 indicates true), and by default is 0.

But when I want to update this column using php,

```
UPDATE .......... SET isSuccessful = 1 WHERE .........
```

it doesn't work.

I tried to set the `isSuccessful` as 1, true, yes, but none of them will work.

So how can I change the values of `isSuccessful`?

Comment: What you describe should work. You must be doing something else wrong. Please post the full query.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are you getting errors? Can you set the value manually in an admin interface? Are you sure your `WHERE` clause matches anything?

Comment: What errors do you get? `SET isSuccessful = 1` this works for me since... ever.

Comment: The problem is probably at the PHP code. Show us some error you get.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made a stupid mistake, the above code works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple update query should suffice. Boolean fields are simply tinyint(1) fields and accept aliases for 1 and 0 as true and false respectively (as strings). The following should be fine. Perhaps if you posted your exact query rather than an abridged version someone might spot a problem?

```
UPDATE `table` SET `isSuccessful` = 1 WHERE `column` = 'criteria'
```

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html : `As of MySQL 5.0.3, a BIT data type is available for storing bit-field values. (Before 5.0.3, MySQL interprets BIT as TINYINT(1).) In MySQL 5.0.3, BIT is supported only for MyISAM. MySQL 5.0.5 extends BIT support to MEMORY, InnoDB, BDB, and NDBCLUSTER. `

Comment: You can also use: `SET isSuccessful = b'1'`

Comment: @ypercube This assumes that the OP set the datatype to BIT. However it's implied that the datatype BOOLEAN was set which implies it's a TINYINT field. BOOL, BOOLEAN

These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html Does this mean `set isSuccessful = b'1'` wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `BOOLEAN` falls into `TINYINT`. My mistake.

Comment: `set isSuccessful = b'1'` would work too (casting bit to tinyint).

Comment: `set isSuccessful = b'11001'` would work too - and set the column to value `25` (binary 11001).

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure you put this  "  `  " character  which is same key of the " ~ "  on the left size of "1" key on the keyboard, that should do it, if you using PHP+ Mysql Under linux.

Comment: not everybody has US layout